# How to find the directory I created using mkdir on Cloudera Hadoop?

Tags: hdfs, cloudera

I am using Cloudera quickstart vm 5.3 for the first time on my virtual machine. The task to is to create a simple text file on my local pc and move it to HDFS, display the contents of the file- all using HDFS commands. I have created a directory using the command that looks exactly like:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -mkdir skk411.
```

The folder got created but I am not able to locate where exactly it got created. I used both, search tool and manually searched all the folders present. But the directory does exist because when I use the same command again, it says "File exists". Someone please help me to find the path.

Answer (score 3):

HDFS is a separate filesystem, so its directories and files do not map directly to directories and files on your local filesystem. HDFS does store its data on the local filesystem but in its own format.

If you want to see what you have in your home directory in HDFS you can run `hdfs dfs -ls`.

Comment: By default, folders are created in the user home directory in HDFS. Hence, in addition you could try `hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera` or `hdfs dfs -ls` (without providing any path).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can open the 'HDFS NameNode' (on the cloudera manager web page) and browse the file system. This way you can simply see all the folders and files in each of them. Hope this helps!